# Logstash - Write file per split event

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I have a Logstash conf where I split an incoming XML into multiple events. I would like to write a file per event. However, the file output writes all the events to a single file (so an event per line). Is there a way to achieve this?

```
.......

filter {

xml{
   store_xml => "false"
   source => "message"
remove_namespaces => true
xpath => 
 [
"/root/Envelope", "Envelopes"         
   ]
  }

mutate {
    remove_field => ["message"]
  }

 split{
  field => "Envelopes"
 }
}

output {
file {
path => "/install/logstash/output-CL102-%{+yyyyMMddHHmmss}.xml"
}
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change the path in the output.  Do you have an 'id' field or some other unique field in the source xml?  If so, use that in the output path.